# Why does my script report ls: not found

Tags: ksh

I have the following korn script:

```
#!/bin/ksh

TAPPDATADIR=/hp/qa02/App/IPHSLDI/Data

echo $TAPPDATADIR

if [[ls $TAPPDATADIR/zip_file_MD5_checksum*.txt | wc -l > 1]]
then
    exit "asdf"
fi
```

When I attempt to run it I get:

```
/hp/qa02/App/IPHSLDI/Data
./iftest.ksh: line 7: [[ls: not found
```

Why isn't my if statement working?

**I'm trying to see if there are multiple checksum files in the Data directory. If there are I want to exit the script.**

Comment: [Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). If you want to count files, use an array: files=($TAPPDATADIR/zip_file_MD5_checksum*.txt) if (( ${#files[@]} > 1 )); then echo "more than one" fi

Comment: Useful info, thank you, although it should really be a comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several problems:

1. There shouldn't be any spaces around `=` in the assignment.
2. You need spaces around `[[` and `]]` in the `if` statement.
3. To substitute the result of a command into the test expression, you need to use backticks or `$(...)`.
4. The parameter to `exit` should be a number, I think you just want to echo the string.
5. `>` performs string comparison, you have to use `-gt` to perform numeric comparison.

So the full script should be:

```
#!/bin/ksh

TAPPDATADIR=/hp/qa02/App/IPHSLDI/Data

echo $TAPPDATADIR

if [[ $(ls $TAPPDATADIR/zip_file_MD5_checksum*.txt | wc -l) -gt 1 ]]
then
    echo "asdf"
fi
```

Comment: +1, but [[ > ]] does a string comparison `[[ $(echo 9) > 10 ]] && echo problem` and `(( $(echo 9) < 10 )) && echo ok`